# Send an array to GET request api and return array back

Tags: mongodb

I have the table:
`User[_id(generated autimatically by mongo),email]`

I also have an array **dataObj.usersId** that looks like this:

```
['648395e2399eaef99a15ef57', '648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7', '648705e0c0a0395aa659251c']
0: "648395e2399eaef99a15ef57"
1: "648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7"
2: "648705e0c0a0395aa659251c"
length: 3
```

I am trying to return the email adress of each UserId:

```
exports.findUsersById = (req, res) => {
  const ids=[req.params.id];
  ids.map((obj)=>{
  User.find({
     _id: obj.id
    }, 'email', (err, user) => {
      
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'User Not found.' });
    }
    ret=[user]
    res.json([...ret,ret])
  });
})
};
```

and here is in react the calling of the request:
**please ignore the first get and iti.map, it workes perfectly but I wanted to show you all the code,just pretend that I send the array from above in dataObj.usersId**

```
useEffect(() => {
    iti.map((dataObj) => {
      return (
        axios
          .all([
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/cities/id/${dataObj.cityId}`),
            axios.get(
              `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/allusersId/${dataObj.usersId}`
            ),
          ])

          .then(
            axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
          //   setCityName({ cityN: res1.data.name, cityC: res1.data.country });

              setUsersName(res2.data);
              console.log(res2.data);
            })
          )
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
      );
    });
  }, [iti]);
```

The console log shows this:

```
{data: Array(2), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
dashboard.tsx:64 (2) 
[Array(0), Array(1)]
```

How can I get back the array with email adresses?